# MediaItem fails to resolve symbol when used with GetMediaUrl in the image source atrribute

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, repeater, sitecore6

What I am trying to achieve is to get the full path of the images, assigning them to the source attribute of the HTML image control. This image is placed within a Repeater Control.

Here the code:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="flashImagesRepeater" >
<HeaderTemplate>
    <table>
        <tr id="bodyImagesTr" >
            <td>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <sc:Link ID="flashImageClickURL" runat="server" Field="Click Url" Item="<%# Container.DataItem %>" >
        <img id="htmlImage" runat="server" field="Image" src="<%# MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(((ImageField)((Item)Container.DataItem).Fields["Image"]).MediaItem) %>" />
    </sc:Link>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</FooterTemplate>
```

Also made sure that I have the relevant namespace added `<%@ Import Namespace="Sitecore.Resources.Media" %>` at the top.

But VS2010 gives me the error

> Cannot resolve symbol 'MediaItem'

Can someone guide me as to what am I doing wrong?

May be the brackets are being being placed incorrectly?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: MediaItem is a member of the Sitecore.Data.Items namespace, not Sitecore.Resources.Media

Comment: Have that included as well <%@ Import Namespace="Sitecore.Data.Items" %>

Comment: What about the `Sitecore.Data.Fields` namespace?

Comment: Don't think it's relevant. I didn't have it so I put it in there. Still the error persists and the namespace appears greyed out suggesting it's not being used.

Comment: Try to bind the image src in the ItemDataBound by using FindControl (use an asp:image control). It's cleaner and you can debug it properly.

Comment: Alright will give that a go. Just thought might not have to write anything in the code behind and achieve the result. Guess not! :-) Thanks Ruud.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't need to write anything in the code behind. It looks like for some reason one of the classes in you statement is considered as not from the one of the `Sitecore` namespaces. Try to use full class names with namespaces:

```
<img 
    id="htmlImage" 
    runat="server" 
    field="Image" 
    src="<%# Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(((Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField)((Sitecore.Data.Items.Item)Container.DataItem).Fields["Image"]).MediaItem) %>"
    />
```

Comment: You don't need to use code behind, but if you were working in my team I'd be pretty mad if you deliver that code ;-)

Comment: @RuudvanFalier totally agree :)

Comment: Maras Musielak will give this a try and see what I get. @RuudvanFalier I have already started taking a different approach.

Comment: Maras Musielak that didn't work either. :-) But thanks for your help. @RuudvanFalier thanks for your help too.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to render an image from a field in an item, just use the FieldRender control and let Sitecore handle it.

```
<sc:FieldRenderer runat="server" FieldName="Image" Item="<%# (Item)Container.DataItem %>" />
```

Comment: One of the aims is also to get the full path in the image.

Comment: In that case bind from code behind and use an `<asp:Image control>`. BTW, the html `<image>` element does not need the Sitecore `field` attribute :)

Comment: I know it doesn't need the field attribute, it was the left over from the Field Renderer that I was trying to make it work. :-) Cheers for the code behind binding.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you are having is that there is that **ImageField** is not resolving to the Sitecore image field correctly.  I pasted that code into an aspx page and I got another error saying that the Field could not be cast as an ImageField.  So I added the sitecore name space to the ImageField conversion and it properly intellisensed **MediaItem** as you wanted.

So change the image tag to this and it should work:

```
<img id="htmlImage" runat="server" field="Image" src="<%# MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(((Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField)((Item)Container.DataItem).Fields["Image"]).MediaItem) %>" />
```

Personally tho - I would use the Sitecore Image control to render the image, if you just want to find the media Url in back end code, the above code would work but could be written a lot more readable :)

Hope this helps!